# Centering content blocks with buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[The `center-block` class of Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-center) is effective in images, in resized block elements (like `div`s) and apparently in buttons.

When **button class** is applied to a **link** (becoming to pseudo-button), it **does not center** horizontally.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default center-block">Pure button</button>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default center-block">Link button</a>
```

The [appearance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) CSS property with `button` value does not work. And setting a fixed dimension (`width`, `max-width` or `min-width`) is not a nice solution.

[This trouble was ignored in GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22732).

Comment: Display: block works in other ways on `button`s and other elements (eg. `a`). You need to add `display: table` to link instead of `display: block;`

Comment: @panther, it is nice! It works!

Comment: @panther, add your answer for accept it.

Comment: @MiquelAl.Vicens: Answer isn't needed when the comment helps you... but I've added it.

Comment: we had exactly the same question, but not able to find :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, mark as usefull then.

Comment: i wanted to link it here so you can also read some other answer maybe they are usefull for you ... but i remember i gave the solution of fixed width an also the solution to use `width:fit-content` that works well but not well supported

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I don't remember this, sorry.

Comment: oh no ! i don't mean you and i had the same question :) i mean on the site i saw the same question like this but no more able to find it so you can see other solutions ;)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you really mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Display: block` works in other ways on `buttons` and other elements (eg. `a`). You need to add `display: table` to link instead of `display: block;`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
a.btn-default {display: table}
</style>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default center-block">Pure button</button>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default center-block">Link button</a>
```

Comment: I would write `a.center-block { display: table; }` (in the style tag) coherently overriding Bootstrap styles.

Comment: @MiquelAl.Vicens: it was just a code snippet which should demonstrate the solution. I personally don't know bootstrap - and in other places you may want centered links. The main point is to add `display: table` to this link. Maybe the better solution is to more specify that we want to center just like-button links, `a.center-block.btn`. There are more ways, without complete code (just from code snippet) isn't possible to choose the best one.

Comment: The correction is over centered pseudo-buttons (like anchor elements). It was clear.